# Edit all conflicting files in a git merge/rebase (special character safe)

Tags: git, shell, git-merge, git-rebase

In the middle of a `git rebase`, I have a status such as:

```
$ git status --short
M  lib/tmuxinator.rb
UU lib/tmuxinator/cli.rb
UU lib/tmuxinator/config.rb
A  spec/fixtures/TMUXINATOR_CONFIG/TMUXINATOR_CONFIG.yml
M  tmuxinator.gemspec
```

How can I open the files with conflicts (denoted `U` above) in my text editor with a single command?

**The solution must work with `\n` and special characters in the filenames.**

Comment: What do you mean by "edit the files"? Do you want to open them in a text editor? Or are you trying to automate resolving the merge conflicts in some way?

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified. However, if you have any tips on auto-resolving, do tell!

Answer (score 2):

Many commands have a `-z`, `-0`, or `--null` option to produce/consume `NUL`-terminated output.

Use the following:

```
git status -sz  | sed -rnz 's/^(U.|.U) (.*)/\2/p' | xargs -0 $EDITOR
```

Or as a `gitconfig` alias:

```
[alias]
  resolve=!"git status -sz  | sed -rnz 's/^(U.|.U) (.*)/\\2/p' | xargs -0 $EDITOR #"
```